# Swift - terminal / command line

Tags: swift

I'm trying to send Python commands via command line.
I am using these functions.
if I use a direct argument like `["flash_id"]` the command works perfectly, while if I insert a more complex argument like `[read_flash 0x00000 0x100000 data.bin]` the command is not executed.
While on the mac terminal it does it.
Where am I wrong?

```
func shell(launchPath: String, arguments: [String]) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = launchPath
    task.arguments = arguments
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    if output.count > 0 {
        //remove newline character.
        let lastIndex = output.index(before: output.endIndex)
        return String(output[output.startIndex ..< lastIndex])
    }
    return output
}

func bash(command: String, arguments: [String]) -> String {
    let whichPathForCommand = shell(launchPath: "/bin/bash", arguments: ["-l", "-c","which \(command)"])
    return shell(launchPath: whichPathForCommand, arguments: arguments)
}


var result = bash(command: "esptool.py", arguments: ["flash_id"] // command executed

var result = bash(command: "esptool.py", arguments: ["read_flash 0x00000 0x100000 data.bin"]. //esptool: error: argument operation:
```

Comment: Do you have the full error message?

Comment: For multiple words, aren't they all arguments? `["read_flash", "0x00000", "0x100000", "data.bin"]`

Comment: Ok thanks, I did as you said and it works perfectly.